# dialogflow agent not ouputting text from inside HTTP request callback

Tags: node.js, httprequest, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to get data from an external site triggered by the welcome intent. Right now I'm trying a simple `GET` request to `google.com`.

The agent works as expected except when called from insided the request callback. It sometimes works and sometimes desn't.

```
'use strict';    
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; 

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  function search(agent){

          var request = require("request");
          var options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://google.com'
          };

          console.log("Before request");
          agent.add("Before request");

          request(options, function (error, response, body){
            console.log("Request completed");
            agent.add("Request completed");     //<- This line doesn't show in agent
            console.log("finished");            //<- This line shows in the log
          });

          console.log("Request sent");
          agent.add(`Request sent`);
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', search);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

I have noticed in the log the message `"Function execution took 1697 ms, finished with status code: 200"` shows before the message `"finished"`. I don't know if that means that process is closing and ignoring the `agent.add()` calls after that point.

[Image: firebase log console showing function excecution finished before request compelted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmOgl.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the callback/promise.
You need to return a promise inside your search function.

```
function search(agent, query){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
      .....
      agent.add(...)
      resolve();
     });
   });
};
```

The original answer can be found in the following Github issue:

https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/3

**EDIT:**

Got a little help from the DialogFlow support staff. I little varation was missing to the proposed code to work properly:

```
function search(agent, query){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
      .....
      let output = agent.add(...)
      resolve(output);  //<- agent.add() should be passed as argument in resolve()
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work. `agent.add()` method works but from inside the request callback. I'll add the update on the question.

Comment: I've updated my question with a very simplified code. That same code, it sometimes shows the agent output and sometimes desn't.

Comment: As I mentioned before your function functionWithHTTPRequest(agent needs to return the promise). Otherwise the agent (webhookclient request) is already resolved. Did you try to return a promise? Also, you need to club all the agent.add commands after the promise is resolved. I guess you cannot send a agent.add and then wait for another agent.add inside request callback.

Comment: Your code was very close to the solution. Just the parameter in `resolve(output)` was missing. I still don't get how or why this Promises in the agent pipe, but now it' working. Thank you.